# What happens when voltage divider output exceeds acceptable voltage of microcontroller ADC? Can it destroy it?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, adc

Imagine you want to measure higher voltage using ADC of some MCU, such as that used in Arduino boards. Those are usually operating at 5V and can only read values in range of 0 - 5V.

So you create a voltage divider let's say with 100k Ohm on `Z1` and 10k on `Z2`

[image: Voltage divider]

From 0 up to 55V you will be getting 0-5V on `Vout` so you are going to be able to reliably measure up to 55V. Problem is that anything higher than 55V on `Vin` is going to result in output voltage higher than 5V on `Vout`.

Now if you connected say 80V power source to `Vin`, you get 7.2V on `Vout` - could this fry the MCU or would the impedance of voltage divider protect it by limiting the current that goes through? Is this safe to do?

Comment: 100 Meg in parallel with 10k is still 10k within 1%, so 7.2 (actually 7.27) is correct.

Comment: Some of microcontrollers, for instance PICs, have diode from input to Vcc.

Comment: You can tune your Z1, Z2 to map a higher range of voltages to 0-5V, so 80V becomes 5V and 55V becomes 3.4375V. This will ensure that you never exceed 5V at the cost of having a lower resolution for your desired range.

Comment: Diodes like this https://www.nexperia.com/products/diodes/switching-diodes/low-leakage-current-switching-diodes/#/p=1,s=0,f=,c=,rpp=,fs=0,sc=,so=,es=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not safe.  There's usually an ESD structure on the input pins that may clamp the input voltage to the supply rail.  It may handle a few mA of current, so if your divider impedance is high enough you might get away with it.

However, it's usually not guaranteed, (unless explicitly stated) and applying any voltage greater than the abs max rating in the datasheet is unwise and of course may damage the device.

You could try adding an external Schottky diode to clamp the input to the rail, but they are leaky and could affect the accuracy of your reading. You might be able to split the upper resistor and use an appropriate lower leakage TVS device to clamp the voltage, or buffer the divider with a circuit that can handle your max input voltage.

Comment: A TVS is for dissipating fast transients rather than acting as a sort-of-Zener. Among other things, they have a very inaccurate clamping voltage as that's suitable for ESD dissipation. The BAT54 (or similar) that I spookily predict @PStechPaul will recommend in the future is a better idea, clamping to the rail like you suggest.

Comment: A BAT54 Schottky diode has only 1 uA leakage at 25C, but 5 uA at 60C and 100 uA at 100C. With a 10k sampling resistor at 5V (500 uA), leakage at room temperature will be negligible, and may cause 2% error at 60C, which might be acceptable. This should be OK for overvoltage protection, but accuracy and operation of all analog circuitry may be unpredictable while the overload exists.

Comment: @TonyM There are many types of TVS diodes, some are rated for very high currents, not just ESD and can be used as a zener replacement.  The clamping voltages ARE inaccurate, but you can find some that are not terrible and might be good enough for the OP's application depending on the requirements.  It's not clear that the OP ISN'T trying to protect against fast transients either.

Comment: Well, the OP clearly states they're thinking of "*say 80V power source*", so protecting against transients would just be guesswork. And if they wanted a TVS to clamp fast transients, it'd go across the terminals, not through a series resistor. But my point isn't that a TVS can't do it (it's just a component meeting a set of specifications) but that it's a poor choice and there's far better alternatives, like the diode to rail which is simple and, being relatively very accurate, has predictable behaviour.

Comment: @TonyM Fair enough, I was thinking about the case where the Schottky has too much leakage current, maybe 2% error is too much.  Then a low-leakage TVS like these (typ 1 nA) could be used to clamp the input voltage with enough series resistance so that it could take a significant overvoltage all day:  https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PTVSXS1UR-Q_SER.pdf  Was just trying to provide alternatives.

Comment: Thanks and I did see your train of thought and tried to lay that out in my first comment. I don't think its good advice to leave there, a TVS through a resistor, future readers might misuse that as a recommendation and TVS are for direct connection to transient connector/cables/etc. If you'd choose to reword your answer to remove the TVS part, I think you'd leave behind a very good answer that I'd upvote and delete all my comments. You can see and delete yours, leaving a tidier webpage. Sad to see my 'spooky prediction' comment go, chance doesn't come along very often, but there we go :-)

Comment: @TonyM Not sure I agree that a TVS shouldn't be used in that way.  As far as I know it's similar to a Zener with improved peak current capability due to junction area, bond wires (if applicable) and improved dynamic impedance. As long as it's thermally OK, I don't see why it can't work.  Maybe you could explain, or others will chime in and if there's a good reason not to use a TVS in that way I'll edit my answer.  (For example a 20K resistor and 50V TVS with a 100V source would dissipate about 125 mW, with 130 K/W would result in a rise of 15.25 degrees. )

Comment: It's as explained above, its inaccurate voltage threshold linked with the effects of the series resistance make it a poor choice compared to better options. The diode's just the clear winner by so far, for me. TVS seem to come up on this site a lot, they're one of the more misused parts it'd appear, and I always avoid a lengthy discussion on them as its in their datasheets and app notes already at length. It's like 'why can't I use neon panel indicators to light a room'. You can - but it's not what they're optimised for, they'll do it badly and there's far better alternatives

Comment: @TonyM Well, for me the ultra-low leakage, reasonably accurate threshold and availability of appropriate breakdown voltages makes the particular part that I linked attractive for a low continuous current application that can't deal with the higher leakage of a Schottky diode.  Otherwise, I'd agree that a TVS isn't targeted at continuous current applications.  So I'll let my answer stand, and people can read your comments which are valid caveats against the idea.

Comment: Thanks for a reasoned exchange and I think that's a fair pov for you to take on it.

Answer (score 2):

> *Now if you connected say 80V power source to Vin, you get 7.2V on Vout - could this fry the MCU or would the impedance of voltage divider protect it by limiting the current that goes through? Is this safe to do?*

The data sheet will probably indicate that the maximum MCU input voltage is around 5.3 volts and, 5.3 volts is exceeded if the input voltage is greater than 58.3 volts: -

[image]

However, if the MCU data sheet states that the maximum input pin current is (say) 1mA then you might decide that 0.5 mA is acceptable and it's a different scenario: -

[image]

So, you may be able to get over 100 volts at the input without over-stressing the MCU input. I think 80 volts stands a reasonable chance of being fine. However, if the input is an analogue input, you won't magically extend the ADC input range; maximum discernible voltage will occur close to 5 volts on the pin.

Comment: Why dont you model the ADC input impedance of the MCU as a 100Meg resistor(the value for Arduino)?

Comment: @GNZ Because it is insignificant. Once the input protection diode starts conducting, the 100M input impedance becomes even more insignificant.

Comment: @GNZ micro-cap is free and has a full library of parts so, maybe you might want to try this out. https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12.zip

Answer (score 0):

To answer this part:

> What happens when voltage divider output exceeds acceptable voltage of microcontroller ADC? Can it destroy it?

Usally the MCU specifies an acceptable main supply voltage (Vdd) range and the Vref of the ADC is usually specified in relation to Vdd (in practice often something like 5V +- 0.2V or similar). Though some parts have a special supply of the ADC in addition to the Vref pin, to allow cleaner analog supply.

If your Vref goes above Vdd limits or in case the ADC input goes beyond Vref, then if you are lucky the MCU activates low-voltage detect and/or some manner of latch-up, protecting itself until the voltage is removed. If you are unlucky, there's a puff of smoke. Or if you are particularly unlucky there is *no* puff of smoke but the ADC is damaged, but the rest of the MCU keeps working just fine, but you get haywire reads from the ADC (been there, done that).

To counter it, you can either pick a Vref with margins or you can protect the ADC input as demonstrated in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Do not do that. Microcontroller is made of thousands of small devices, called transistors. They basically work like tiny electric switches. Exceeding the voltage overheats them and makes them burn, which will destroy the microcontroller.